# Frozen clothes during the Nine Days

Tags: halacha, clothing, nine-days, current-events

Recently, [some have advocated freezing clothing, particularly blue jeans, instead of washing them to conserve water.](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/11/02/science/earth/levi-strauss-tries-to-minimize-water-use.html?_r=1&hp)

Assuming this works to some extent, can it be done during the Nine Days? Can I wear freshly frozen jeans during the Nine Days if they were frozen beforehand?

Comment: Purim Torah?...

Comment: @SethJ No it's a real question. It's just funny.

Comment: @SethJ I know there is discussion in the gemara already about launderings of different quality (Bavel vs Israel or something) and there is discussion about which level is really assur. So I'm guessing there could be what to say about this issue.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2157/759

Comment: @SethJ Also it could open discussion about non-water based cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

When stains start coming off it is called washed. Source: gemara moed katan

Comment: Hi opoil. How do you know this? Please [edit] in a source. Since we don't know you, there's no reason we should just take your word for this.

Comment: Where in Moed Kattan does it say that? If it's referring to laundering on Chol HaMoed, how do you know the same rules would apply to the nine days?

Comment: It is not the halaca only what is called washed and that is what it says in gemara

Comment: Hi Opoil Yutrol. Welcome to MiYodeya. Maybe you will be interested to read something I wrote ["A beginner’s guide to MY - How is this site different from other Judaism sites”](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites)
 ? This site relies heavily on sources, as precise as possible (e.g., the specific place in the gmara) ideally linked (e.g., using sefaria.org)